# Непонятная генерация больших чисел

Tags: python

Я новичок в програмированье (1.5 месяц) решал задачю  в проекте Элера (2 задача "Четные числа Фибоначчи") написал код. Код работает, но только есле в while находится только один аргумент, если я добавляю второй аргумент появляются непонятные большие числа. Почему они появляются я не понял.

```py
def v_q () :

    a = 1  # 1
    b = 2  # 2

    while a or b < 20:
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        print(a)
        print(b)

v_q()
```

Comment: `while a or b < 20` --> `while a < 20  or b < 20`

Comment: Пытаюсь найти связь между заголовком и текстом и не нахожу.

Answer (score 4):

У вас `while a` делает цикл бесконечным, ибо `a` всегда  больше нуля

Answer (score 0):

По сути Вам нет смысла проверять является ли `а` меньше 4 млн.(вместо 20 из задачи Эйлера), так как `a` всегда будет меньше `b`, по-этому можно проверять только второе число `b`.
Я бы сделал так:

```py
def v_q ():
    summ = 0
    a = 1
    b = 1
    while b < 4000000:
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        if b % 2 == 0:
            summ += b
    return summ
vz = v_q()
print(vz)
```

Comment: Труъ-код выглядит так: `a, b = b, a+b`.

Comment: И по сути нет смысла проверять числа на четность вообще. Каждое третье число Фибоначчи - четное. Нужно считать каждое третье и складывать без проверок.

Comment: @Эникейщик, какой же ты вредный, нет слов. Я делал по примеру автора. 
Чтобы посчитать каждое третье слово надо всё-равно выводить последовательность, тогда уж проще посчитать через filter lambda

Comment: Не вредный, а наоборот полезный. Рассказал как упростить и ускорить код.